# When will jvm load the imported classes for instanceof operator?

Tags: java

Suppose I have two classes A and B.

```
class A{}

import A;
class B{}
```

Then if on some object I do in `main` method `if(object instanceof B)`, will it load class `A` as well as it is there in the import statement of class `B`?
When exactly will classloader load these classes on runtime?

Comment: If `B` only references `A` via a redundant import, `A` will never be loaded solely because of `B`.

Comment: @user207421 Yes but will class B be loaded when i am evaluating (object instanceof B) given that object is not really in the hierarchy of B ?

Answer (score 5):

There are two things to note:

1. An `import` statement does not affect the runtime behavior of a class.  No code whatsoever is generated for the import statement.  And if you simply import class A in class B, then loading class B does not cause class A to be loaded.
2. Class load time and class initialization time are different.

The life-cycle of a class is that it is load, linked and initialized before it is used (See [JLS Chapter 12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html)).

- Loading is performed by a classloader, and involves locating the classfile, reading it into a `byte[]` and calling `ClassLoader::defineClass`.
- Linking is performed by JVM core code, and consists of verification, preparation and resolution of symbolic references.  The [JLS 12.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3) says this:

  > This specification allows an implementation flexibility as to when linking activities (and, because of recursion, loading) take place, provided that the semantics of the Java programming language are respected, that a class or interface is completely verified and prepared before it is initialized, and that errors detected during linkage are thrown at a point in the program where some action is taken by the program that might require linkage to the class or interface involved in the error.

  This means that we cannot be specific about when the different tasks are performed.
- Initialization occurs after all relevant classes have been linked.  According to [JLS 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

  > A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
  >
  > - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
  > - A static method declared by T is invoked.
  > - A static field declared by T is assigned.
  > - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

---

According to the JLS (see above) we cannot say precisely when `B` will be loaded and linked.  All we can say is that it happens before `B` is initialized ... if it is initialized.  (You can gain insights into the order of class loading by turning on some JVM logging.  However, the order may vary depending on JVM vendor and version.)

According to the JLS (see above) initialization of `B` will occur (typically) when the first instance of `B` is created by your `main` method.  Assuming that `object` in your Question has been initialized to a `B` instance, initialization will have already happened before the `instanceof` test.  If not, then `B` won't be initialized by the `instanceof` test.

On the face of it, there is no need for class `A` to be loaded.  (It depends whether and how class `B` actually uses class `A`, and whether / how other parts of your codebase uses `A`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the answer. However, I have additional doubt that, how this (object instanceof B) will be evaluated. Even if the object is not an instance of 'B', does it not require class B to be loaded to actually evaluate (object instanceof B) ?

Comment: The class `B` will be loaded when the symbolic references in your main class are resolved. In the scenario in your comment, `B` won't be initialized.

Comment: I'd be at least a little surprised, actually, if it had to do anything with B.  If B hasn't been loaded, then certainly a given object isn't an instance of it, or else B would've been loaded to create the instance...

Comment: There is an implied reference to the type of `B` in `instanceof` be.  That means that the main classes classfile has a symbolic reference to B ... which must be resolved before the static initialization of the main class.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it this way:

Main.java:

```
package test;

import test.sub.B;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("Creating object");
      final B b = new B();
      System.out.println("instanceof check");
      if (b instanceof B) {
         // Do nothing
      }
   }
}
```

A.java:

```
package test;

public class A {
   static {
      System.out.println("Class A loaded");
   }
}
```

B.java:

```
package test.sub;

import test.A;

public class B {
   A a;

   static {
      System.out.println("Class B loaded");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Creating object
Class B loaded
instanceof check
```

So, neither a import, nor the declaration (`A a;`) does load a class.

This fits to the statement from wikipedia: `The Java Class Loader [...] dynamically loads Java classes [...]. [...] This loading is typically done "on demand", in that it does not occur until the class is called by the program. [...]`

When you change the `A a;` in class `B` to `A a = new A();` then the class `A` will be loaded.

Comment: This is incorrect.  What you are actually showing is when the `B` class is **initialized**.  Class load and class initialize times are not the same.

Comment: It also doesn't answer the question.